# PostgreSQL, Linq C# error 'could not determine data type of parameter $1'

Tags: c#, linq, postgresql

I am getting this error `"could not determine data type of parameter $1"`
and my where clause where I am getting the error is like the following:

```
var result = from Table in model.Table 
                             where (filter.XId.HasValue ? Table.XId == filter.XId: true)

                             select new TableEntity
                             {
                                 ID = Table.XId
                             };
```

If my code was only like this 'Table.X == filter.X', it works ...
How can I fix this?

and I am getting this problem only with PostgreSQL database ....

Comment: Replace that condition with "filter.X == Table.X || filter.X == null"

Comment: @Evk I want only to add this condition in where if the filter coming to the method has a value, and I will be filtering the table values, if I wrote Table.X == filter.X I will be getting wrong values if filter.X is null ....

Comment: This is not how it works. Actually your current statement will be converted to quite ugly and long SQL condition (you can check yourself). My proposed statement will achieve exactly the same result (if filter is null it will be ignored) but with less ugly statement, and (maybe, didn't check) it will also work fine with PostgreSQL. If you don't want to include condition _at all_ if filter is null - check it for null _before_ Where statement, not inside it.

Comment: @Evk if I did like this "filter.X == Table.X || filter.X == null", would not I get the table values where x == null if my filter does not have a value

Comment: No, this condition is exactly identical to yours - if filter.X is null - ignore condition (" : true" part of your statement). Does it help by the way, no error in postgre?

Comment: LINQ doesn't generate SQL. The underlying ORM/LINQ provider does. Which ORM are you using? Most likely it tried to convert `HasValue` to a SQL statement and failed. For example, EF's provider for SQL Server would have thrown an error explaining that it can't map `HasValue`.  Evk already explained how to write a correct `where` clause

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos while I agree with you in general, EF provider for SQL server will not throw a error in this case, but instead will convert it to quite ugly and long condition.

Comment: @Evk thanks alot, it works great if you can add it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First about what that error usually means. When making parametrized queries to PostgreSQL, all parameters should be referenced in query itself. When you add more parameters than used in query, usually the error above appears.

It seems that when whatever EF provider for PosgreSQL you use converted your statement to SQL, it created more parameters than needed.

In general, it might be hard for EF providers to analyze and correctly parse statements like you used, so good practice is to use statements that are "closer" to SQL in certain sense. In your case equivalent query which is "closer" to SQL would be:

```
where (filter.XId == null || Table.XId == filter.XId)
```

If you want to generate *different* queries based on the value of filter, you can do something like this:

```
var query = (IQueryable<Table>) model.Table;
if (filter.XId != null) {
    query = query.Where(row => row.XId == filter.XId);
}
var result = query.Select(row => new TableEntity {
    Id = row.XId
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is the first SO answer in Google -
Marked answer didn't help me in similar case (EF6 + Postgre), so I had to use .AsEnumerable();

Yeah, it could be bad for perfomance but it fitted well in my case.

So this one would work:

```
var query = model.Table
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Where (p => filter.XId.HasValue ? p.XId == filter.XId: true);
```